# How to find 3rd part of location pathname?

Tags: javascript

I want to get 'second' in the following sample web address.

http://www.mywebsite.com/first/sedond/third.html

"first" can be any length. i.e. contact, images etc

If I use document.location.pathname, I get "/first/sedond/third.html".
If I use document.location.pathname[1], I get "f".

How can I get "first" part by using document.location.pathname?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked two different questions - here are both answers. 8-)

**"How can I get 'first' part"** - like this:

```
// Strip the first slash, else IE and FF give different results.
var pathname = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
var parts = pathname.split(/\//);
var result = parts[0];
```

**"I want to get 'second'"** - like this:

```
// Strip the first slash, else IE and FF give different results.
var pathname = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
var parts = pathname.split(/\//);
if (parts.length > 1 ) {
    var result = parts[1];
    document.write(result);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: Do the regexes need the "g" flag?

Comment: @Josh: Empirically no, but I couldn't easily find any official documentation to back that up.